# RESTKit 0.20 - Logout and Clear Authorization Header

Tags: oauth-2.0, restkit, afnetworking, restkit-0.20

What's the best practice to Logout and clean up the Authorization Header, etc. with RESTKit 0.20?

Will this method suffice?

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [self getObjectManager];
[objectManager.HTTPClient clearAuthorizationHeader];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use one of the `setAuthorizationHeaderField*` methods on the http client to add the authorisation then calling `clearAuthorizationHeader` is the correct approach to take.

If you explicitly set the header or parameter then you need to clear that header or stored attribute.